# Net send from Sql Server 2000 to Windows 7

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server Agent job that fails every once and a while. This has become a problem because I recently upgraded to windows 7, and so I no longer get the notifications for the failures.

The computer doesn't have outlook installed on it, so I can't set it up to send email notifications until I figure that part out.
I'm hoping someone knows a trick to make the netsend notifications work when routed to a computer with windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the net send and pager notifications are scheduled to be deprecated from future versions of SQl Server.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx

It would be wise to get database mail setup. It uses Service broker and CDO and no longer require outlook MAPI profile to be configured,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175887.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You could try [xpsmtp](http://www.sqldev.net/downloads/xpsmtp/default.html) which was put together to allow prehistoric SQL Server versions to send SMTP emails.
The last 3 releases of SQL Server have SMTP mail built in of course...

Comment: I've got something like this already, where I put an extra step at the end of the job that all failures point to (on failure go to step 5) which would notify me of the error. The downside to this is that it would always show an error on step 5, so I would never know which step was the original failure point. Know of a way to more seamlessly integrate this into the notification system?

Comment: Frankly, upgrade... you have no local MAPI client for SQL agent mail and net send is blocked in later OS. Bummer. Your options are very limited...

Comment: Upgrading is possible. it's something that we've talked about doing. Do the newer versions of SQL Server have better ways of doing this? We are really having a hard time getting outlook installed on that machine for some reason.

Comment: @AndyD273: yes, SQL Server 2005 has built in SMTP support. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175887%28SQL.90%29.aspx No MAPI needed

Answer (score 1):

i don't think you can net send to other computers anymore. not since like windows xp.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

http://www.petri.co.il/msg-exe-net-send-vista.htm

You can't use net send after Windows XP.

Comment: Can this be integrated into the notification system? I'm working on getting the normal SQL Mail working, but in the mean time it would be nice to have something like this working.